# Magento 2.2.5 Mini cart not showing items or subtotal

Tags: magento2.2, mini-cart

Magento 2.2.5 - upgraded from 2.1.5 last week but not sure it was working on 2.1.5

Site is under development. The mini cart in the header is not working properly. When you add something to the cart it says, 1 item available, that part is correct. However the subtotal is not appearing at all and the items are not appearing

The following error is in the console:

```
 knockout.js:3012 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)) }"

    Message: Cannot read property 'simple' of undefined

at UiClass.getItemRenderer (minicart.js:140)
```

which refers to these lines in minicart.js

```
getItemRenderer: function (productType) {

return this.itemRenderer[productType] || 'defaultRenderer';

//return 'defaultRenderer';

},
```

Console log shows "simple" for productType

If I comment out the return line and just return "defaultRenderer" it gives no errors but just no items.

This was using a custom Theme, not made by me but even reverting to Default Blank theme still gives the same error.

"itemRenderer" is in **vendor/magento/magento-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_car_sidebar_item_renderers.xml** and other similar questions seem to imply that there is an issue in the XML but I can't see anything wrong with it. Any ideas?

ETA-----------

I am still struggling with this. I installed 2.2.5 locally and took the vendor/magento/magento-checkout files and put them in this site, just in case, and deleted the module-checkout files from the app/design theme folder and it's still giving the same error. I have deployed static files, cleared cache etc etc. Is there anything else I could be trying?

Comment: Just to update, upgraded to 2.2.6, finally got it to work after setting up new themes, testing, adding files into the app/design/ theme folders bit by bit and now back at the original theme and it's working. Didn't actually change anything in the end but it's working